What's the difference between に関わる and と関わる?
What is the difference between に関わる and と関わる? I've seen it a couple of times and seems almost inter-changable
お前は今日の集まりには 一切関わるな！
(に関わる)
概していえば、この種の問題では直接人々と関わる人が好きだ。
(と関わる)
My only guess would be ''と関わる'' is a mutual relationship with each-other ''Having to do something with a person (with each-other)'' while に関わる seems one sided ''To be concerned with something/someone'' Am I wrong?
(P.S.)
In the と関わる sentence how would you translate ''で'' in ''では'' ?
Does it indicate context/situation of action? F.ex ''In X situation I would have done Y action''
Or does では have a different meaning here?
I've heard it could mean ''When it comes to X topic'' but I could be wrong.
Please let me know if that's the case.

They're almost always interchangeable, and the difference is subtle, but I think と might signify a slightly deeper sense of involvement. "Aに関わるB" may be a little closer to "B related to A", and "Aと関わるB" to "B involving A".

how would you translate ''で'' in ''では'' ?

Yes, it's a scope/condition particle. It's just "in (the context of) this type of problem" here.

Yeah heard the で in では can mean ''When it comes to'' or as you said ''in the context of'' The puzzle pieces are starting to make sense. Glad the question made sense though and seems to be correct within my guess.
